# Python function type hint with predefined type

Tags: python, types

In Python, we can create aliases or custom types like following:

```
MyKindOfFunction = Callable[[int, int], int]  # alias
AlternativeType = NewType('AlternativeType', Callable[[int, int], int])  # new type
```

Consider the following function:

```
def myfunc(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

Obviously, the signature matches the above definitions. Is there a more convenient way of notating this than annotating the parameters manually? I am unhappy with the way it is annotated for the following reasons:

1. It does not check against `AlternativeType`, as `AlternativeType` is a subclass of `Callable[[int, int], int]`.
2. I am using many higher level functions, with equivalent signatures, but are logically of different types, and I would like to be able to differentiate between them.